# Proof writing help: Let $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $x+y = 1$. Let $m = \min\{x,y\}$. Show that $m \leq 2xy \leq 2m$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing

I'm trying to get better at writing proofs. I'm stuck on proving a simple statement:

Let $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $x+y = 1$. Let $m = \min\{x,y\}$. Show that $m \leq 2xy \leq 2m$.   $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathrm{(i)}$

*Current attempt*: W.l.o.g., say $\min\{x,y\} = x$ and note that $x \in [0,1/2]$. It's clear that $2x^2 \leq x \leq x + 2x^2 $. The result follow from here: $ 0 \leq x - 2x^2 \leq x \implies x \leq 2x - 2x^2 \leq 2x \implies m \leq 2x(1-x)\leq 2m \implies m \leq 2xy \leq 2m$, where we substitute $y = 1- x$ in the last step.

My issue is that I assert two things without proof:  (ii) $\min\{x,y\} \in [0,1/2]$ and (iii) $2x^2 \leq x \leq x + 2x^2 $. I'm struggling to concisely prove these statements because they seem so "obvious".

How would you prove (ii) and (iii)? Do you have a different approach to proving (i)?

Comment: Say "Without loss of generality let $x\le y$."  This will let you say that $x+y = 1$ implies $x\le \frac  12.$  As for $x\le 2x^2 + x$ this is true because $x^2 \ge 0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $x>\frac12$; then $y=1-x<1-\frac12=\frac12$, so $\min\{x,y\}=y$, contrary to the assumption that $\min\{x,y\}=x$. Thus, we must have $x\le\frac12$ and hence $x\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$.

In $2x^2\le x\le x+2x^2$ the second inequality follows from the fact that $2x^2\ge 0$ for all $x$. The first inequality takes just a little more work: the inequality is equivalent to $x-2x^2\ge 0$, i.e., to $x(1-2x)\ge 0$. Solving this, we find that $0\le x\le\frac12$, so it is indeed true that $2x^2\le x$ for $x\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$.